# Stop hover after specific time period CSS or Pure JS

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I'm trying to find a way to show an hover for a specific time and stop it.
I'd like to show a background for 1 second and then hide it even when the mouse is still on.
My preferences are in css or javascript but I'd like to keep jquery out of my code.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdeav3zg/) of my current code.

```
#social {
    min-width: 350px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    word-spacing: 25pt;
}
#social a {
    padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#social a:hover {
    color: transparent;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CSS animations](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/), something like:

```css
#social {
  min-width: 350px;
  font-size: 11pt;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 3vh;
  word-spacing: 25pt;
}

#social a {
  padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;
  color: #999999;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#social a:hover {
  animation-name: background;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes background {
  from {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #999;
  }
  to {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="social">
  <a href="#">showreel</a>
  <a href="#">linkedin</a>
  <a href="#">instagram</a>
  <a href="#">vscocam</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#social {
    min-width: 350px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    word-spacing: 25pt;
}
#social a {
    padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#social a:hover {
    color: transparent;
 animation: backg 5s;
 -webkit-animation: backg 5s;
}

 @keyframes backg
    {
      0%   {background: red;}
      50%  {background: red;}
      100% {background: white;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes backg 
     {
      0%   {background: red;}
      50%  {background: red;}
      100% {background: white;}
    }
```

```html
<div id="social">
  <a href="#">showreel</a>
  <a href="#">linkedin</a>
  <a href="#">instagram</a>
  <a href="#">vscocam</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an animation and keyframes to do that. In this case, your animation would look like:

```
@keyframes hover-effect {
    0% {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #999999;
    }

    1% {
        color: transparent;
        background: red;
    }

    100% {
        color: transparent;
        background: red;
    }
}

.class:hover {
  animation: hover-effect 1s ease;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/gk3nfmnj/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css animation` to get it.

like following

```css
#social {
  min-width: 350px;
  font-size: 11pt;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 3vh;
  word-spacing: 25pt;
}

#social a {
  padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;
  color: #999999;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#social a:hover {
  animation: hover 2s;
}

@keyframes hover {
  from {
    background: transparent;
  }
  to {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="social">
  <a href="#">showreel</a>
  <a href="#">linkedin</a>
  <a href="#">instagram</a>
  <a href="#">vscocam</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !